# iPhone web app - splash screen not working

Tags: iphone, web-applications, splash-screen

I have 2 web apps with the same meta tags (for testing purposes) linking to the same file to use as a splash screen.

one app is absolutely fine - not a worry and works fine anytime on any device.

the other app does not want to know about it - how come the splash screen seems so temperamental??

BTW - the app icon works fine, so I know the directory is set right - also note I am using the same image, so the specs for that are also correct.

Comment: "does not want to know about it" is not a useful bug or problem description. Please describe the actual problem. Do you mean the splash screen doesn't appear? What do you mean by 'temperamental'? That it works only sometimes?

Comment: do a clean build, see if that fixes it...

Comment: @occulus - Sorry if it is to vague - one web app does not show it all and the other shows it all the time, but the settings are the same. Hope that clarifies it:-) --Jeff

Comment: @MCannon - Yes I have done several rebuilds, code changes and re-uploads to the server. Hence I am asking for help on this form:-)

Comment: It looks like this does not work in iOS 10 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into this problem quite a bit and it is almost always caused by calling more than one splashscreen or the splashscreen not being 320x460 pixels (exactly). This should do the trick:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash-iphone.jpg" />
```

But before calling the splashscreen, you should include these three lines of code as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Having multiple web apps referencing the same splashscreen file shouldn't be a problem, but not the other way around.

Comment: cheers for that tip - I will work on it when I get back to work tomorrow and share my findings:-)

Comment: Yep, thanks for that - the docs (http://bit.ly/1sXMLxX) say 320 x *480*, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the 320x460 px remark made by the previous poster, you can actually specify a different splash image for retina-capable devices.  This solution works for me:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash/splash.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="img/splash/splash@2x.png">
```

Splash.png should be 320x460 px and splash@2x.png should be twice that, at 640x920 px.